# Scheduling with quartz every minute from 14:00 to 17:30

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am having problems scheduling my job with quartz... I cannot find an expression which lets me run my job from 14:00 to 17:30 every minute... I have tried this

```
0 0-30/1 14-17 ? * MON-FRI
```

but not works

Comment: *"but not works"* Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Comment: using this expression the pollar runs at 14:00 to 14:30 then 15:00 to 15:30 and so on till 17:30. but i want it run from 14:00 to 17:30 every min

Comment: Better to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16561275/edit) that information back into the question.

Comment: sorry for my wrong expression i have used 0 0-30/1 14-17 ? * MON-FRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring I would do it this way

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 14-16 * * *")
public void schedule1() {
    schedule2();
}

@Scheduled(cron="0 0-30 17 * * *")
public void schedule2() {
    System.out.println(new Date());
}
```

or in xml config

```
<bean id="test" class="test.Test" />

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="test" method="schedule2" cron="0 0 14-16 * * *"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="test" method="schedule2" cron="0 0-30 17 * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

note that in xml config you can use one method. That trick with annotations was because we cannot use 2 annotations of the same type on one method.

Comment: i am using it in spring by puttting the expression in a pollar-context.xml . can you tell how can i define two bean property for cron expression..i mean the exact syntax

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create two Cron Expressions in order to achieve this.

1. from 14:00 to 17:00
2. 17:01 to 17:30

**0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? ***  this is the cron expression for every minute. Apart from this refer http://www.cronmaker.com/ . With this you will be able to generate expressions.

Comment: I didn't think about this solution. Seems better than mine (see comment). +1 to you.

Comment: thanks @dystroy . Basically when talked about generating cron expression between time range, we generally used to do this. :)